# The Json file produced with Scrapy is empty

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I'm trying to learn Scrapy, and executed the programs shown in Scrapy at a glance, and the following tutorial.
Running the commands with `-o file.json -t json` produce a json file full of empty fields:

```
$ cat test.json  
[{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
...
{},
{},
{}]
```

It doesn't seems to be due to data not existing, because if my output is an CSV file, content is saved:

```
body,votes,tags,link,title  
"<div class=""post-text"" itemprop=""text"">

<p>Here is a piece of <strong>C++</strong> code that seems very peculiar. For some strange reason, sorting the data miraculously makes the code almost six times faster.</p>

<pre class=""lang-cpp prettyprint-override""><code>#include &lt;algorithm&gt;

...
```

I precise that being on the computer of my university, it shouldn’t be a problem on the configuration of Scrapy.

Does anyone knows what I missed to have a working json file? Or is the json export broken and has to be done manually through pipelines? The documentation insist that pipelines are not necessary when one just needs to export the output.

EDIT:
code  of the first example:

```
import scrapy


class StackOverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('.question-summary h3 a::attr(href)'):
            full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_question)

    def parse_question(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.css('h1 a::text').extract()[0],
            'votes': response.css('.question .vote-count-post::text').extract()[0],
            'body': response.css('.question .post-text').extract()[0],
            'tags': response.css('.question .post-tag::text').extract(),
            'link': response.url
        }
```

Code of the second example:
items.py:

```
class TeststackoverflowItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    subject = scrapy.Field()
    score = scrapy.Field()
    bestAnswer = scrapy.Field()
```

spider.py

```
import scrapy
from testStackOverflow.items import TeststackoverflowItem

class SpiderStackOverflow (scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stackoverflow"
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    #though it looks like it gives the same result without ?sort=votes, it's not the case with a wget
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes']

    def parse(self, response):
        for div in response.css('div.question-summary h3 a::attr(href)'):
            full_url = response.urljoin(div.extract())
            #print ('full url: ', full_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_question)

    def parse_question(self, response):
        item = TeststackoverflowItem()
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract() #works
        item['subject'] = response.css('.post-text').extract()
        item['score'] = response.css('.question .vote-count-post::text').extract()[0] #works
        item['bestAnswer'] = response.css('.answercell').extract()[0]
        yield item
```

Shell final output in the case of the second example:

```
2016-04-01 16:14:51+0200 [stackoverflow] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-04-01 16:14:51+0200 [stackoverflow] INFO: Stored json feed (50 items) in: top-stackoverflow-questions.json
2016-04-01 16:14:51+0200 [stackoverflow] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 23724,
     'downloader/request_count': 51,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 51,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 2154436,
     'downloader/response_count': 51,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 51,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 14, 14, 51, 769488),
     'item_scraped_count': 50,
     'log_count/DEBUG': 101,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'request_depth_max': 1,
     'response_received_count': 51,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 51,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 51,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 51,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 51,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 14, 14, 43, 691509)}
2016-04-01 16:14:51+0200 [stackoverflow] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Sources:
  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html#walk-through-of-an-example-spider
  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Comment: Let me see your code

Comment: @danmash the code has been added

Comment: ok, give me five minutes

Comment: Your code works fine for me, do you see output to the shell when you run it? It looks more like you are getting nothing returned which may be for many different reasons.

Comment: second example works fine. You use `scrapy runspider  stackoverflow/spiders/test_spider.py -o top-stackoverflow-questions14.json -t json` ?

Comment: @danmash yes, I just used the command again in case, but my json file is still like I shown in my post, existing, not empty, but each field is empty, and the shell shows me the json output file that should be created.

Comment: try `scapy crawl test_spider -o top-stackoverflow-questions.json`

Comment: @danmash still the same problem, I add to the post the final output of Scrapy's shell

Comment: @khorgn, so `top-stackoverflow-questions.json` is empty?

Comment: @khorgn, you should run scrapy with different output files every time. New items are added to an already extracted items. Maybe you see the head of output file, which consist of old items

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The file itself is not empty, it is like shown in the post, the json object saved in the file has this form:
[{}, {}, {}, ..., {}]
Objects are created, but they contains nothing, even though according to the shell ouput, the Json objects created contain data

Comment: @danmash I've just deleted the file to check, the generated file is still in the same situation has before.

Comment: What version of scrapy are you using and where are you running it from?

Comment: I'm running it from my university's computer, the current version installed is Scrapy 0.25.0-454-gfa1039f according to --version

Comment: well, that explain everything if the version installed on the computers of my university is completely outdated

Comment: Yep, just update and you should be fine, if you have pip I would recommend installing with that.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I actually don't have the rights to update or install anything on the machines of my university, but I sent at mail to the admins, thank you for your help